# Geometry of moduli problem in practice: how to check it is connected / irreducible / normal / reduced / locally complete interesection...?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, moduli-spaces

Moduli spaces are very common and useful in the world of algebraic geometry. From the point view of functors, one can already check many geoemtric properties of it. I like examples, and you can assume the base is $\mathbb C$ for simplicity, but I also enjoy rings like $\mathbb F_p$ and $\mathbb Z[1/N]$.

To show it's proper, we have the valuation criterion which is very useful (once we know some "locally finite type" assumptions). For instance, one can prove Hilbert scheme is proper over the base directly, moduli of stable curves $\bar{\mathcal{M}_g}$ is proper over $\mathbb Z$ using stable reduction theorem, many moduli spaces of polarized varieties of special types are proper over $\mathbb C$ using some hard boundness results... And many other causes can be reduced to closed subschemes of Hilbert schemes.

To show it's (locally) finite type, we often do an explicit "counting", e.g in the explicit construction of Hilbert schemes.

To show it's smooth, we have the infinitesimal lifting criterion which is very useful. Another way is that we can use deformation theory to compute the dimension of tangent space at a point, if the dimensions are all the same everywhere, then we win by generic smoothness and the simple definition of regularness by dimension.

To show it's projective, one firstly shows it's proper, and find an ample line bundle by some universal constructions.

These are well-known techniques. But in practice, **how to show it is connected / irreducible / normal / reduced...? How to count irreducible components**? For instance, Hartshorne proves Hilbert scheme with given Hilbert polynomial is connected, Deligne and Mumford prove $\bar{\mathcal{M}_g}$ is irreducible, both using some explicit deformations.

**How to show it's Cohen-Macaulay / locally complete intersection / regular**? We can reduce to local rings, and there is a theory of local models to deal with singularity in some cases, based on linear algebra computations.

And how about other geometric properties? Thank you very much for the examples and ideas.